# Why does the LIKE SOQL operator implicitly translate picklist values?

Tags: soql, translation, translation-workbench

Assume, I've got a standard picklist field `Rating` on `Account` with values `Hot`, `Cold`. Using enabled `Translation Workbench` I've translated these values into German.
When the language of a user is set to `English`, and the user performs a SOQL query

```sql
SELECT Id, Rating FROM Account WHERE Rating LIKE 'Cold'
```

it returns `N` records. But if we change the language of the user to `German`, the same SOQL query returns `0` records. However, when it changes to

```sql
SELECT Id, Rating FROM Account WHERE Rating LIKE 'Kalt'
```

it returns `N` records as well as for the very first scenario. At the same time, the returned values of the `Rating` field remain untranslated ('Cold'). This means that the `LIKE` operator implicitly translates the values of picklists before comparison. I've tested `IN`, `NOT IN`, `=` SOQL Comparison Operators and they don't behave like `LIKE`, they perform a comparison based on picklist value `API Name` not `Label`. There is no such information about it in Salesforce Docs.
So finally my question is:

> Why does the `LIKE` SOQL operator implicitly translate picklist values before comparison and how to perform a comparison based on picklist value API Names using the `LIKE` operator?

Comment: You have come across [**this known issue**](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4HUAA0).

Comment: Thanks @JayantDas for providing the link. I was looking for the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I thought was the reason for the `LIKE` operator to automatically translate picklist values, and that [has been confirmed on the documentation since Spring '21](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm): The `LIKE` operator is used to match strings. The picklist value is translated, probably because of situations when the end-user searches for text in his own language.

Consider the following situation: a custom search component for a multinational company that supports many languages. The requirement is to enable search in picklist values that are being added/deactivated every month or so. If the user wants to search for a string, he won't type the API name of the field, but the translated version of the value he wants to get.

[image: cheese translation picklists]

Comment: Great explanation. But if this behavior is expected it should be mentioned in Docs.

Comment: The part where I said the LIKE is used to match strings is written on the documentation. The rest is conjecture.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

Since `Spring 21 (API Version 51.0)` the [Translate Returned SOQL Results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm) paragraph of Apex Docs was updated by adding the limitations:

> - The `LIKE` operator can only query on the label of the picklist, **not on its API name**.

That means that the behavior described in the question is expected and now officially documented, and we should consider it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a why for you, but if you have a scenario where LIKE needs to match the API name, you could create a formula field targeting the same picklist. FFs always return API name not label.