# SOQL LIKE operator on picklist field appears to fetch results based on matches on label not API value

Tags: soql

SOQL LIKE operator on picklist field appears to fetch results based on matches on label not API value.

For example, take this query

```
SELECT Id, Name, RZone__Type__c FROM RZone__PSPayment__c
WHERE RZone__Type__c LIKE ‘%Migration%’
```

> Here RZone__Type__c is a picklist

[image]

This query returns records with a Type API value of “Advance” because the label is “Balancing Payment Data Migration”. I would expect to see the like operator applied to the API value and not the label.
From the [documentation](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf) The LIKE operator can only query on the label of the picklist, not on its API name - This limitation applies only to translated picklist values. The doc doesn’t say why does the like operator queries on the labels even though translation used

I came across this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285076/why-does-the-like-soql-operator-implicitly-translate-picklist-values) where it said If you have a scenario where LIKE needs to match the API name, you could create a formula field targeting the same picklist. Formula fields always return API name not label.

Can anyone please advise if this is working as designed? Thanks for your inputs

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there isn't a way to filter based on API name when the operator is LIKE unfortunately. This is a limitation today

The following limitations apply to translated picklist values:
・The LIKE operator can only query on the label of the picklist, not on its API name.

As per this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm) , If no translation is available for the picklist, the comparison is made against the master values.